# laravel 5.5.45 Carbon 1 deprecated error?

Tags: php, laravel-5, composer-php

I have installed laravel 5.5.45 using composer. Composer version is 1.18.4 and PHP version is 7.0.3. development and production server are in the same configuration.

I tried to install dompdf package. But I am getting following message

```
Carbon 1 is deprecated, see how to migrate to Carbon 2.
https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-carbon-2
You can run ".\vendor\bin\upgrade-carbon" to get help in updating carbon and other frameworks and libraries that depend on it.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover
Discovered Package: arcanedev/log-viewer
Discovered Package: fideloper/proxy
Discovered Package: laravel/tinker
Discovered Package: laravelcollective/html
Discovered Package: maatwebsite/excel
Discovered Package: nesbot/carbon
Package manifest generated successfully.
```

I tried with following changes.

```
"require": {
"nesbot/carbon": "2.24.0 as 1.39.0"
"kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2": "^1.0.0"
}
```

It produces following error

```
Problem 1
- Installation request for nesbot/carbon 2.24.0 as 1.39.0 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[2.24.0].
- nesbot/carbon 2.24.0 requires php ^7.1.8 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 2
- Installation request for nesbot/carbon (locked at 1.39.0, required as 2.24.0 as 1.39.0) -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[1.39.0].
- nesbot/carbon 1.39.0 requires php ^7.1.8 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
Problem 3
- nesbot/carbon 2.24.0 requires php ^7.1.8 || ^8.0 -> your PHP version (7.0.30) does not satisfy that requirement.
- kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 1.0.0 requires nesbot/carbon ^2.0.0-beta.2 -> satisfiable by nesbot/carbon[2.24.0].
- Installation request for kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2 ^1.0.0 -> satisfiable by kylekatarnls/laravel-carbon-2[1.0.0].
```

i cant upgrade the php version in production and development server. So please help me to solve this  without updating PHP version

Comment: "_nesbot/carbon 2.24.0 requires php ^7.1.8_" Looks like you can't without updating PHP. Why can't you update PHP?

Comment: @kerbholz Thanks for your reply. Many core php and framework application are running in the production server with php 7.0 . So I need to go with  the configuration. Is there any alternate way to work with carbon 1?

Comment: So you're stuck with PHP7.0 forever? Are those apps using PHP7.0 specific functions that are not available in PHP>7.0? "_Carbon 1 is deprecated_" - I wouldn't recommend using it.

Comment: [PHP 7.0 reached end-of-life 9 months ago](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php). Please consider upgrading your server. Upgrading from .0 to .3 is painless, and you'll gain security and performance (and some new features).

Comment: You simply can't upgrade to Carbon  without upgrading PHP. So you are stuck with a deprecated version of it as long as you run an obsolete PHP engine. There is nothing to fix, I'm afraid.